# Can Compiz prevent overlap with a specific application window?

Tags: compiz, window, screen

I would like to reserve screen space for an application, i.e. prevent other windows from overlapping with it when they open or maximize. Can Compiz do that? and how?

Comment: Maybe you could just keep the window always on top (option available after right-clicking the title bar)?

Comment: Nope, that's not comparable. Imagine if your gnome-panel was always on top rather than having reserved space. But thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it isn't possible (Ubuntu 11.04). If that changes in time please let me know so I can edit this post.